# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int^{2x}_{x}g(t)dt}{x^2}$ assuming $g(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, derivatives

Assume $g(x)$ is differentiable everywhere .So $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int^{2x}_{x}g(t)dt}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int^{2x}_{0}g(t)dt-\int^{x}_{0}g(t)dt}{x^2}$. But the problem here is how do you know $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \int^{2x}_{0}g(t)dt-\int^{x}_{0}g(t)dt=0$ (so we can apply lhopital later)?

suppose we know $\int^{2x}_{0}g(t)dt-\int^{x}_{0}g(t)dt=0$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int^{2x}_{0}g(t)dt-\int^{x}_{0}g(t)dt}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{2g(x)-g(x)}{2x}$ (not sure if the variable is correct) $=\frac{g'(0)}{2}$.

Could someone clear my confusion?

Comment: It's not that the difference is equal to zero, it's that when you take a limit as $x\to 0$, the difference is zero. Incidentally, both terms go to zero when you take the limit.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, but why is the limit$x\to 0$ of the difference equal to $0$?

Comment: Do you also assume $g$ is continuous at zero?  You will need this...

Comment: TFC 1 States that if $g:[0,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $G(z)=\int_0^zg(x)dx$, then $$G'(z)=g(z)-g(0)\qquad\text{for }z\in[0,b]$$ Then, from the Chain Rule we have $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\,x}\int_0^{2x}g(t)dt=g(2x)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\,x}(2x)-g(0)=2g(2x)-g(0)$$

Comment: @CoolKid both of the individual integrals converge to $0$ since you're effectively evaluating $\int_0^0 g(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

TFC 1 States that if $g:[0,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $G(z)=\int_0^zg(x)dx$, then $$G'(z)=g(z)-g(0)\qquad\text{for }z\in[0,b]$$ 
So, from the Chain Rule we have $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^{2x}g(t)dt=g(2x)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}(2x)-g(0)=2g(2x)-g(0)$$
Then we have, from L'Hopital's Rule:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{2x}g(t)\,\mathrm d t}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2g(2x)-g(x)}{2x}\\[3pt]
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2g(2x)-2g(0)}{2x}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{2x}\\[3pt]
&=2\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(2x)-g(0)}{2x}\right)-\frac12\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac32g'(0)
\end{align*}
Since $g$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: How did you achieve $\lim\limits\frac{2g(2x)-g(x)}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2g(2x)-2g(0)}{2x}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{2x}$

Comment: @CoolKid: Since $g(0)=0$, then...